# Run python until it succeeds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a way to run my python code until it succeeds.

Currently my python code is connecting to a database and takes all the data available and formats the data in a desired format. The problem is that sometimes the database, that the code is accessing, is empty. Yet sometimes the database contains data which I would like to access.

Ideally I would like to start my python code and the code should run until it finds data and saves the data accordingly.

Comment: Please share the code as well!

Comment: You can probably use a while loop with try/except

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
while True:
    try:
        # do something
    except SomeError:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

where the `else` part is executed only when no exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to this would be to put in a while loop which looped until the result from the database contains rows. I'd also put in another clause to escape the loop by pressing a key too so you can exit the program cleanly.